# Get frames per second of a gif in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, gif, animated-gif

In python, im loading in a gif with PIL. I extract the first frame, modify it, and put it back. I save the modified gif with the following code

```
imgs[0].save('C:\\etc\\test.gif',
           save_all=True,
           append_images=imgs[1:],
           duration=10,
           loop=0)
```

Where imgs is an array of images that makes up the gif, and duration is the delay between frames in milliseconds. I'd like to make the duration value the same as the original gif, but im unsure how to extract either the total duration of a gif or the frames displayed per second.

As far as im aware, the header file of gifs does not provide any fps information.

Does anyone know how i could get the correct value for duration?

Thanks in advance

Edit: Example of gif as requested:

[image]

Retrived from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rotating_earth_(large).gif).

Comment: You can get the frame delay in centiseconds with **ImageMagick** if you don't find anything better at and of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31194595/2836621

Comment: A GIF does not indicate fps because each individual image can have a timing of its own. Is that a potential problem? If not, add them all up and divide by the number of frames.

Comment: @usr2564301 This is not a problem since the frames will always have equal duration, and as such i would be able to calculate the framerate from that, but i do not know how to get the individual duration of the frames, do you?

Comment: I don't know but the GIF format is extensively described elsewhere. There might even be some ready-made code around. In the mean time, can you add such a GIF to your question?

Comment: There's an animated GIF in the answer I linked to above, with its per-frame delays listed out.

Comment: When you use PIL’s Image.open(), you can get a ImageObj.info() dict, which has `duration` as a key. See: [Pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#gif)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In GIF files, each frame has its own duration. So there is no general fps for a GIF file. The way [PIL supports this](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#gif) is by providing an `info` dict that gives the `duration` of the current frame. You could use `seek` and `tell` to iterate through the frames and calculate the total duration.

Here is an example program that calculates the average frames per second for a GIF file.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

FILENAME = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                        'Rotating_earth_(large).gif')

def get_avg_fps(PIL_Image_object):
    """ Returns the average framerate of a PIL Image object """
    PIL_Image_object.seek(0)
    frames = duration = 0
    while True:
        try:
            frames += 1
            duration += PIL_Image_object.info['duration']
            PIL_Image_object.seek(PIL_Image_object.tell() + 1)
        except EOFError:
            return frames / duration * 1000
    return None

def main():
    img_obj = Image.open(FILENAME)
    print(f"Average fps: {get_avg_fps(img_obj)}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you assume that the `duration` is equal for all frames, you can just do:

```
print(1000 / Image.open(FILENAME).info['duration'])
```