# Extract delay between each GIF frame in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif

I am developing a program in Python which creates a video from an HTML file.
The HTML file may contain one animated GIF, and I need to keep the animation in the final video.

I already managed to extract each frame from the GIF, inspired by the method provided in the following GitHub Gist:

https://gist.github.com/revolunet/848913

> ```
> import os
> from PIL import Image
>
>
> def extractFrames(inGif, outFolder):
>     frame = Image.open(inGif)
>     nframes = 0
>     while frame:
>         frame.save( '%s/%s-%s.gif' % (outFolder, os.path.basename(inGif), nframes ) , 'GIF')
>         nframes += 1
>         try:
>             frame.seek( nframes )
>         except EOFError:
>             break;
>     return True
>
>
> extractFrames('ban_ccccccccccc.gif', 'output')
> ```

I replaced the GIF source in the HTML with each of these frames, and generated all the frames of the final video using PhantomJS.

Now, I need to get the duration of each frame in the source GIF file, in order to reproduce it in the corresponding frame of the video.

I found no way to achieve this in Python.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53365469/2836621

Comment: Yes, it helped! Thanks!