# PIL failing to provide frame duration when opening animated WebP files (Python)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, webp

I am writing a program in python that batch converts animated WebP files to GIFs but i am running into an issue where i cannot determine the framerate of the original file as i PIL wont return the duration of each frame.

Currently i am using the PIL library to open and analyse the WEBP files. According to other posts online and PIL documentation i should be able to see the duration of each frame by using *.info* but currently all I do get is the "Loop" and "background" properties.

I am using the webp file linked here to test the code:
https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/animated-webp
Using other webp files has the same issue so I'm pretty sure its not unique to this file.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

def webp_gif(filename, outfile):
    imagefile = Image.open(filename)

    #checking frame by frame fails too
    for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(imagefile):
        frameinfo = frame.info
    
    #This throws an error 
    duration = 1000 / imagefile.info['duration']
    images = processImage("%s" % filename)
    fps = duration / len(images)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you cannot get the delay from PIL, so this is actually a suggestion of a workaround that is too long for a comment.

You used to be able to get the delay like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53365469/2836621).

---

You can get the delay/duration and disposal method for all frames in your image using **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick animated-webp-supported.webp -format "Frame: %s, Dispose: %D,  Delay (centiseconds): %T\n" info:


Frame: 0, Dispose: None, Delay (centiseconds): 7
Frame: 1, Dispose: None, Delay (centiseconds): 7
Frame: 2, Dispose: None, Delay (centiseconds): 7
Frame: 3, Dispose: None, Delay (centiseconds): 7
Frame: 4, Dispose: None, Delay (centiseconds): 7
Frame: 5, Dispose: None, Delay (centiseconds): 7
Frame: 6, Dispose: None, Delay (centiseconds): 7
Frame: 7, Dispose: None, Delay (centiseconds): 7
Frame: 8, Dispose: None, Delay (centiseconds): 7
Frame: 9, Dispose: None, Delay (centiseconds): 7
Frame: 10, Dispose: None, Delay (centiseconds): 7
Frame: 11, Dispose: None, Delay (centiseconds): 7
```

If you want to use Python, you can do exactly the same as above with `wand` https://pypi.org/project/Wand/ which is a Python ctypes-binding for **ImageMagick**.

---

You can also get the delay using `exiftool` as follows:

```
exiftool -duration animated-webp-supported.webp

Duration                        : 0.84 s
```

And if you want to do that with Python, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708133/2836621) answer. I have not investigated why the two tools report different values.