# How to add gif image inside a Kivy Popup?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have a popup in my app and works great. It shows a Text as well but i want to add a gif inside it, but i could not success.

I will share my structure.

**KV File:**

```
<PopupBox>:
    pop_up_text: _pop_up_text
    pop_up_image: _pop_up_image

    background_color: '#38B6FF'
    background: 'white'
    size_hint: 1, 1
    auto_dismiss: True
    title: 'FOOTBALL PREDICTOR'
    title_size: '15dp'
    title_font: 'fonts/Bungee-Regular.ttf'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: _pop_up_text
            text: ''
            font_name: 'fonts/Bungee-Regular.ttf'
            font_size: '30dp'
            color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1 
        AsyncImage:
            id: _pop_up_image
            source: ''
```

**Python File:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.utils import platform
if platform == 'android':
    from kivmob_mod import KivMob
from time import sleep
from unidecode import unidecode
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import requests
import threading
import re
import ssl       

class PopupBox(Popup):
    pop_up_text = ObjectProperty()
    pop_up_image = ObjectProperty()

    def update_pop_up_text(self, p_message):
        self.pop_up_text.text = p_message

    def update_pop_up_image(self, image_url):
        self.pop_up_image.source = image_url    

class Predictor(BoxLayout):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Predictor, self).__init__(**kwargs)
 
        self.status = True

    @mainthread
    def on_size_calculate(self, *args):
        self.ids.sv_calculate.scroll_y = 1
        print('Scroll 1')
        self.pop_up.dismiss()
        print('Popup Dismiss')    


    @mainthread
    def on_size_guide_eng(self, *args):
        self.ids.sv_guide_eng.scroll_y = 1
        print('Scroll 3') 
        self.pop_up.dismiss()
        print('Popup Dismiss')

    @mainthread
    def on_size_guide_tr(self, *args):
        self.ids.sv_guide_tr.scroll_y = 1
        print('Scroll 4') 
        self.pop_up.dismiss()
        print('Popup Dismiss')           
               

    def homepage(self, s_image, screenmanager):        
        
        screenmanager.current = 'homepage_screen'

    def league(self, s_image, screenmanager):        
        
        screenmanager.current = 'league_screen'   
                
    def show_popup(self):
        self.pop_up = Factory.PopupBox()
        self.pop_up.update_pop_up_text('''Please Wait...\n...Be Patient''')
        self.pop_up.update_pop_up_image('wait.gif')  # Replace 'path_to_your_gif.gif' with the actual path to your GIF file
        self.pop_up.open()

    @mainthread
    def clear_widgets(self, *args):

        if self.ids.gridsonuc.children:            
            for child in [child for child in self.ids.gridsonuc.children]:            
                self.ids.gridsonuc.remove_widget(child)
            print('Screen Cleared')

        if self.ids.guidesonuc_eng.children:            
            for child in [child for child in self.ids.guidesonuc_eng.children]:            
                self.ids.guidesonuc_eng.remove_widget(child)
            print('Screen Cleared')

        if self.ids.guidesonuc_tr.children:            
            for child in [child for child in self.ids.guidesonuc_tr.children]:            
                self.ids.guidesonuc_tr.remove_widget(child)
            print('Screen Cleared')                      

    def calculate_screen(self, s_image, screenmanager, lig):
        
        screenmanager.current = 'calculate_screen'
        self.show_popup()
        mythread = threading.Thread(target=self.clear_widgets) 
        mythread.start()
        mythread3 = threading.Thread(target=self.calculate(lig)) 
        mythread3.start()
        mythread4 = threading.Thread(target=self.on_size_calculate) 
        mythread4.start()    

    @mainthread
    def calculate(self, lig, *args):
    

        async def fetch_stats_home(session, url, match_codes_home):
                  
            "some codes"  

        async def fetch_stats_away(session, url, match_codes_away):

            "some codes"       

        async def main():
            url = 

            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                tasks_home  = [fetch_stats_home(session, url, match_code) for match_code in match_codes_home]
                tasks_away  = [fetch_stats_away(session, url, match_code) for match_code in match_codes_away]
                await asyncio.gather(*tasks_home, *tasks_away)

        asyncio.run(main())         

    veri = []
    veri.append(calculate)          

class FootballpredictorApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Predictor()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FootballpredictorApp().run()
```

[image]

As you can see there are white cicles. `'wait.gif'` is in the root, as main.py.
I can see `Please Wait` text but gif does not seen. I did not used `from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage` in pure python. I am not good at Python, Kivy As well.
Could you pleae help me to fix this problem?

Thousands Thanks for each Comment.

**UPDATE: A CLUE **

I run this app in Vscode and in terminal when the popup closes i get this error:

```
Scroll 1
Popup Dismiss
Unknown <gif> type, no loader found.
```

Comment: What is your current kivy version ?

Comment: Also you could try to change the kivy display environment as explained here in the documentation. If the problem is a about an incompatibility between the format of the image and the config you are using, it might help. https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/environment.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, as per [doc](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.anim_delay)  you need to specify the anim_delay (in other words 1/fps, whats the duration of each frame)

You can get the value using python PILLOW library (can only get the average), here's a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53365469/11071949)

sample code, modifying `update_pop_up_image`

```py
from PIL import Image

def get_avg_fps(path):
    """ Returns the average framerate of a PIL Image object """
    img_obj = Image.open(path)
    img_obj.seek(0)
    frames = duration = 0
    while True:
        try:
            frames += 1
            duration += img_obj.info['duration']
            img_obj.seek(img_obj.tell() + 1)
        except EOFError:
            return frames / duration * 1000
    return None


class PopupBox(Popup):
    pop_up_text = ObjectProperty()
    pop_up_image = ObjectProperty()

    def update_pop_up_text(self, p_message):
        self.pop_up_text.text = p_message

    def update_pop_up_image(self, image_path):
        self.pop_up_image.source = image_path //make sure the image is available on the device, not some online URL
        self.pop_up_image.anim_delay = 1/get_avg_fps(image_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply I tried this code but not worked. I found that i can add `anim_delay: 2` via KV file under 'AsyncImage:' as well but that did not worked either. And i checked log and now it says `bad transparency mask`

Comment: you can try fixing it with some online image converter, not sure it'll work. It worked for me on a old project (https://github.com/RaSan147/VoiceAI-Asuna/blob/8ff3fb892eb2c92ae632431ace0c4ff61dcff417/src/KV_gui0.kv#L26) really well, or at best you can try changing the gif with something else

Comment: It is too strange that i tried a png and jpg file also but same error :D