# Reverse the morph by starting images

Tags: imagemagick

I have created the morphing animation using image magick. i am using this reference page [Imagemagick transitions between multiple images -- need idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189695/imagemagick-transitions-between-multiple-images-need-idea)

I have used this code to do the above

```
convert -delay 20 *.jpg -morph 14 g2b.gif
```

And now i am getting perfect animation for one way. means it is animated from start point to end point. but i want the reverse way also.

There are 2 images and i want to create a morphing animation from both side.

I have got one way animation from the two images.

```
convert -delay 20 *.jpg -morph 14 g2b.gif
```

I want the animation from both side. From the start point and the from the end to start point in the reverse order.

[image: This is the first image]

[image: This is second image.]

I got this image by using the above command.

[image]

I want to reverse animation also. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try:

```
convert -delay 20 whitecar redcar whitecar -morph 14 g2b.gif
```