# Create fade-in and fade-out gif in R magick package

Tags: r, gif

I have been trying to find a way to create a fade-in and fade-out gif in R using the magick package, but haven't been able to find any help in the documentation, or online.

Using the code below, I can "fade-out" from the first picture to the second. But instead of the loop jumping back to the beginning of the sequence, I would like it to fade-in in reverse.

Here is the code for fading-out from the first picture to the second. What do I have to add to then fade-in backwards to get back to the beginning?

```
library(magick)
newlogo <- image_scale(image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/Rlogo.png"))
oldlogo <- image_scale(image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/Rlogo-old.png"))
my_gif <-  image_resize(c(oldlogo, newlogo), '200x150!') %>%
  image_background('white') %>%
  image_morph(10) %>%
  image_animate(fps=5, optimize = TRUE) %>%
  image_browse(my_gif)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701676/reverse-the-morph-by-starting-images) from the imagemagick website helped me find a solution. Just append the first image to the end to have three images in total, rather than two. Here's the code that worked:

```
library(magick)
newlogo <- image_scale(image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/Rlogo.png"))
oldlogo <- image_scale(image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/Rlogo-old.png"))
my_gif <-  image_resize(c(oldlogo, newlogo, oldlogo), '200x150!') %>%
  image_background('white') %>%
  image_morph(10) %>%
  image_animate(fps=5, optimize = TRUE) %>%
  image_browse(my_gif)
```

Comment: Can you stop prior to `image_animate`, save that as a `tmp` object, and then feed that entire result into where you would normally have `oldlogo` in the original code?

Comment: I'll try your suggestion later, but I've found a solution from here. You simply add the original image to the end of the images like this:


image_resize(c(oldlogo, newlogo, oldlogo), '200x150!')

Comment: Cool. That sounds simpler. You can answer your own question below by the way. It gives you more imaginary internet points too.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution from the imagemagick help pages. You simply have to append the initial image to the end to have three images--1st--2nd--1st. And that way it will seem like the gif is "fading in" and "fading back out."

Here's the code:

```
library(magick)
newlogo <- image_scale(image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/Rlogo.png"))
oldlogo <- image_scale(image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/Rlogo-old.png"))
my_gif <-  image_resize(c(oldlogo, newlogo, oldlogo), '200x150!') %>%
  image_background('white') %>%
  image_morph(10) %>%
  image_animate(fps=5, optimize = TRUE) %>%
  image_browse(my_gif)
```